# Extract input address from a namecoin transaction given a 'name' operation

Tags: python, bitcoin, blockchain

I have been trying to extract input addresses from Namecoin transactions using some python code. This code works for regular transactions (where some namecoins are transferred from one address to another); however, this doesn't work on the transactions which have **name** operations, such as name_new. Here is some code:

```
raw = namecoind.getrawtransaction(tx_hash)
data = namecoind.decoderawtransaction(raw)

if 'vin' in data:
    inputs = data['vin']
    for input in inputs:
        input_value = input.get('value')

        if 'scriptSig' in input:
            script_sig_asm = str(input['scriptSig'].get('asm'))
            script_sig_parts = script_sig_asm.split(' ')
            if len(script_sig_parts) > 1 and (len(script_sig_parts[-1]) == 130 
                or len(script_sig_parts[-1]) == 66):
                public_key_string = script_sig_parts[-1]
                try:
                    recipient_address = NamecoinPublicKey(public_key_string, verify=False).address()
                    print recipient_address
                except Exception, e:
                    print str(e)
                       return
            elif len(script_sig_parts) == 1:
                print "coinbase transaction input"
                return


    #print "Inputs:"
```

Running this code on a regular transaction works, i,e, we get the recipient address. But running this code for a name operation such as [this](http://explorer.namecoin.info/tx/ad7bc255e5fc6e3b88345d34ccdd2773fdf39d87a8c73308a286969415d25b9d) shows that its a coinbase transaction, that is,

> len(script_sig_parts) == 1

is True, and so the recipient_address is empty.

Can anybody point me how I can get the recipient address (in the above transaction, it is: NCAzVGKq8JrsETxAkgw3MsDPinAEPwsTfn) in a Namecoin transaction which involves name operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should work fine (but I have not tested it) on most name transactions.  For instance, if you take `499a1e4c7bb1388347e1bd1142425949971eaf1fa2521af625006f4f49ce85c5` (which is the latest update of `d/domob`), the relevant script sig of the input is this:

```
"scriptSig" : {
  "asm" : "3045022100c489ac648d08416d83d5e561d222049242242ded5f1c2bfd35ea48bb78b6a90f02203a28dee3d9473755fc2288bcaec9105e973e306071d28e69e593668c94b19fc101 04a85b7360b6b95459f7286111220f7a1eaef23bc9ced8a3b56cd57360374381bcabf7182941be400ccdfb761e26fa62d50b8911358aceb6aa30de9e8df5c46742",
  "hex" : "483045022100c489ac648d08416d83d5e561d222049242242ded5f1c2bfd35ea48bb78b6a90f02203a28dee3d9473755fc2288bcaec9105e973e306071d28e69e593668c94b19fc1014104a85b7360b6b95459f7286111220f7a1eaef23bc9ced8a3b56cd57360374381bcabf7182941be400ccdfb761e26fa62d50b8911358aceb6aa30de9e8df5c46742"
},
```

As you can see, it *does* have two pieces in the scriptsig.  (The pubkey and the signature.)  For your transaction, however, the previous output is not pay-to-pubkeyhash but instead pay-to-pubkey.  Here's the relevant output of the previous `92457dfc2831bdb6439fc03e72dbe3908140d43ec410f4a7396e3d65f5ab605b`:

```
"scriptPubKey" : {
  "asm" : "046a77fa46493d61985c1157a6e3e498b3b97c878c9c23e5b4729d354b574eb33a20c0483551308e2bd08295ce238e8ad09a7a2477732eb2e995a3e20455e9d137 OP_CHECKSIG",
  "hex" : "41046a77fa46493d61985c1157a6e3e498b3b97c878c9c23e5b4729d354b574eb33a20c0483551308e2bd08295ce238e8ad09a7a2477732eb2e995a3e20455e9d137ac",
  "reqSigs" : 1,
  "type" : "pubkey",
  "addresses" : [
    "NCAzVGKq8JrsETxAkgw3MsDPinAEPwsTfn"
  ]
}
```

Due to the nature of the pay-to-pubkey script, the script sig does not contain the pubkey anymore (just the signature).  I don't see a way to find the input address just from the script sig.  If you want to handle these (rare) cases, you have to fetch the previous output and see there.  (My knowledge about ECDSA is limited -- maybe there is a way to extract the pubkey from the signature.)

Comment: Thanks Daniel for the answer. So you mean to say, that I should inspect that vin, and within that find the previous txid, and then check that transaction to find the address?

Comment: Yes.  In general, the previous `vout` is the place to look for the address.  I understand it that you try to avoid that, and your strategy should work most of the time.  But in case it doesn't (like with this example), you have to look at the previous output.  (Also be aware that there may be totally non-standard scripts in the blockchain, where the spending `vin` can be about anything.  Probably not many, but they could exist.)

Comment: @Ibrahim: By the way, your tx example is not a coinbase tx. It is an "abandoned" name_new tx. The required name_firstupdate tx simply does not exist. Have a look at  
http://namecoin.webbtc.com/tx/ad7bc255e5fc6e3b88345d34ccdd2773fdf39d87a8c73308a286969415d25b9d